# Php-fpm service fails to start on solus. Possibly due to snmp module

Tags: php, php-fpm, httpd, systemd, snmp

I am having some trouble to start the php-fpm service on solus OS. It appears that is is maybe related to the snmp module.

Here are some info about the error :

```
~ $ sudo systemctl status php-fpm
Mot de passe :
● php-fpm.service - The PHP FastCGI Process Manager
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/php-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Mon 2021-04-12 11:34:02 CEST; 3min 52s ago
Process: 4958 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/php-fpm --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/php/php-fpm.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 4958 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
CPU: 69ms
avril 12 11:32:32 keynux-fab php-fpm[4958]: Cannot find module (IP-FORWARD-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
avril 12 11:32:32 keynux-fab php-fpm[4958]: Cannot find module (NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
avril 12 11:32:32 keynux-fab php-fpm[4958]: Cannot find module (NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
avril 12 11:32:32 keynux-fab php-fpm[4958]: Cannot find module (UCD-DLMOD-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
avril 12 11:32:32 keynux-fab php-fpm[4958]: Cannot find module (SNMP-NOTIFICATION-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
avril 12 11:32:32 keynux-fab php-fpm[4958]: Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TM): At line 0 in (none)
avril 12 11:32:32 keynux-fab php-fpm[4958]: Cannot find module (NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
avril 12 11:34:02 keynux-fab systemd[1]: php-fpm.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
avril 12 11:34:02 keynux-fab systemd[1]: php-fpm.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
avril 12 11:34:02 keynux-fab systemd[1]: Failed to start The PHP FastCGI Process Manager.
```

When I try to start php-fpm independently :

```
~ $ sudo /usr/sbin/php-fpm --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/php/php-fpm.conf
Mot de passe :
MIB search path: /root/.snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IF-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (TCP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (UDP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (HOST-RESOURCES-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (NOTIFICATION-LOG-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (DISMAN-EVENT-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (DISMAN-SCHEDULE-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (UCD-SNMP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (UCD-DEMO-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-TARGET-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (HOST-RESOURCES-TYPES): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-MPD-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-VIEW-BASED-ACM-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-COMMUNITY-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IPV6-ICMP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IPV6-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IPV6-TCP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IPV6-UDP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IP-FORWARD-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (UCD-DLMOD-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-NOTIFICATION-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TM): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
[12-Apr-2021 11:47:59] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 5410
[12-Apr-2021 11:47:59] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[12-Apr-2021 11:47:59] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
```

It appears to start, however I get 403 "access denied" on all php scripts located in /var/www/
I get the same result (access denied) when I do :

`~ $ sudo systemctl edit php-fpm`
and then enter :

```
### Editing /etc/systemd/system/php-fpm.service.d/override.conf
### Anything between here and the comment below will become the new contents of the file

[Service]
Type=simple
```

then

```
~ $ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
~ $ sudo systemctl start php-fpm
● php-fpm.service - The PHP FastCGI Process Manager
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/php-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/php-fpm.service.d
└─override.conf
Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-04-12 11:57:13 CEST; 1s ago
Main PID: 5588 (php-fpm)
Tasks: 3 (limit: 9349)
Memory: 9.4M
CPU: 61ms
CGroup: /system.slice/php-fpm.service
├─5588 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/php-fpm.conf)
├─5593 php-fpm: pool www
└─5594 php-fpm: pool www
avril 12 11:57:13 keynux-fab php-fpm[5588]: Cannot find module (IPV6-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
avril 12 11:57:13 keynux-fab php-fpm[5588]: Cannot find module (IPV6-TCP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
avril 12 11:57:13 keynux-fab php-fpm[5588]: Cannot find module (IPV6-UDP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
avril 12 11:57:13 keynux-fab php-fpm[5588]: Cannot find module (IP-FORWARD-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
avril 12 11:57:13 keynux-fab php-fpm[5588]: Cannot find module (NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
avril 12 11:57:13 keynux-fab php-fpm[5588]: Cannot find module (NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
avril 12 11:57:13 keynux-fab php-fpm[5588]: Cannot find module (UCD-DLMOD-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
avril 12 11:57:13 keynux-fab php-fpm[5588]: Cannot find module (SNMP-NOTIFICATION-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
avril 12 11:57:13 keynux-fab php-fpm[5588]: Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TM): At line 0 in (none)
avril 12 11:57:13 keynux-fab php-fpm[5588]: Cannot find module (NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
```

The problem seem to be that php cannot find the mibs in /usr/share/snmp/mibs. However, all the mibs are in this folder, so I don't know why it can't find them.
I tried to reinstall net-snmp with no effect.

I was able to reproduce the issue on a fresh solus install : all I did was

- Install httpd and php. Php was working as expected
- Comment the line "extension=snmp" in /etc/php/php.ini
- Restart httpd and php-fpm. Php-fpm service fails without snmp errors.
- Uncomment the line "extension=snmp" in /etc/php/php.ini
- Restart httpd and php-fpm. Php-fpm service fails as described above.

If would be extermely helpful if someone had any idea to solve this problem... I would be happy to provide any helpful log.

php version is 7.3.26.
I didn't change anything to the default php conf, neither the www pool conf.
The only changes I made to the conf are in /etc/httpd/conf.d/httpd.conf :

```
LoadModule deflate_module lib64/httpd/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule rewrite_module lib64/httpd/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule expires_module lib64/httpd/mod_expires.so

#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
ServerName 127.0.0.1

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "/var/www"
<Directory "/var/www">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Thank you for your help.